# How can an AzureAD application revoke consent for itself? (Remove Delegated or Application permissions)

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In the interest of transparency, I want to provide both Administrators and End users the ability to remove my application from their AD profile.

Right now Microsoft wants administrators to use the the AzureAD powershell command `Remove-MSOLServicePrincipal` or to go to the Azure Management Portal.  Or end users can go to the app portal.

Since it's likely that a user will have several organisations or many app authorizations, I want to provide a simple remove option for my subset of applications (whilst informing the user that the MSFT portal exists)

How can I deprovision my app in both the client credential grant flow, or authorization code grant flow?

Answer (score 1):

Permission scopes that have been granted to an application through the consent process are stored in the directory as [OAuth2PermissionGrants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#oauth2permissiongrant-entity).

If your application has the permission to modify these objects, then you would be able to use the Graph API to delete one, which would essentially remove the consent record for that application.

Note that these objects are tied to a specific clientId, which represents the service principal of the client application in your tenant. This is why we ask you to delete the service principal from your tenant as quick way to remove consent, as it would remove all of the tied OAuth2Permissions as well.

You could also use the Graph API to delete your own Service Principal (I have tested this in the past). This would also remove all consent your application would have, based on the details above.

However, to my knowledge, these kinds of permissions are not natively supported through our Public Graph API scopes. I have gained this kind of access by adding my application to the Company Administrator Role in my tenant, which will elevate the graph access it has beyond what is available in our public scopes. However, you have to use PowerShell or something to do that, and at that point, might as well just use that same tool to delete the Service Principal anyway...

Let me know if this helps!